# Do 'side inputs' in Cloud Dataflow support reading from BigQuery views?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Tried to point a side-input to a BigQuery view, instead of directly to a BigQuery table. It does not produce an error, but simply returns 0 rows. View works fine inside BigQuery.

For example, given a view referencing a table 'types_test' with just 1 row:

[image]

In BigQuery, it works fine:

[image]

But using the view as a side-input in Dataflow return 0 rows:

```
INFO: Reading from BigQuery table <removed>:CPT_7414_PLAYGROUND.view_test
Mar 20, 2015 11:10:08 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO evaluateReadHelper
INFO: Number of records read from BigQuery: 0
```

Do side-inputs support views in BigQuery, or do you need to do something else to use a view for a side-input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in the FAQ's, that views are not currently supported.

http://goo.gl/ZVNTnp